# Can you use a past tense lexical verb in a main clause to refer to a future time?

Tags: past-tense

This paper titled "[TENSE AND TIME IN ENGLISH VERB CLUSTERS OF THE PRIMARY PATTERN](http://burnellus.com/tense/files/2010/10/Dudman-1983-Tense-and-Time-in-English-Verb-Clusters-of-the-Primary-Pattern.pdf)" by V. H. Dudman (1983) seems to say the following sentence is possible English (page 27):

> (6) *According to our original plan, the conference **began** next Monday, but now it begins tomorrow.*

Is this sentence really possible English?

1. If not, how come this paper has been quoted in some other papers as well?
2. If so, is this sentence well-formed and/or natural English as well?

Comment: should be "...will begin..."

Comment: I don't think Dudman says that the sentence is possible English; I think you've misread the article.  He rejects many of his numbered sentences as he searches for the guiding principles.

Comment: @Xanne No I think it's you who've "misread the article". I suggest you go re-read the article if you already have. If you were right about me misreading it, all the four "answerers" here must have misread it as well, which is very unlikely. Morover, no one other than you has so far suggested that Dudman says the sentence is impossible English.

Comment: Maybe they haven't read the article.  They don't refer it it, or his argument.

Comment: @Xanne I've read the entire paper, and the paragraph including sentence (6) multiple times. So, I know for a fact that nowhere in the paper is it suggested that sentence (6) is impossible or even unnatural. You'll have to show me exactly where it is said in the paper that sentence (6) is impossible English. Simply quote the relevant lines directly from the paper.

Answer (score 4):

I would construe your sentence

> According to our original plan, the conference *began* next Monday, but now it *begins* tomorrow.

as a case of reported speech, since the official schedule of events is published and known, and the speaker is essentially citing a source.

> The note on the professor’s door said the assignment *was* due next Friday.

The official schedule of the conference said it *began* next Monday, just as the professor’s note said the assignment *was* due next Friday.

Even so, if one is personally involved, i. e., you have to complete the assignment yourself rather than, say, you’re just checking for a friend, the tendency in reported speech is to [use the present tense](https://learningenglish.voanews.com/a/everyday-grammar-reported-speech/2856671.html). Since the original plan is *our* plan, then it would be unusual for a participant in the conference to use the simple past in this instance unless the context you didn’t cite clarifies the matter.

Instead, the construction most often used to describe a change in an announced schedule or plan is [***was*** + marked infinitive](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/youmeus/learnit/learnitv103.shtml).

> **Hotfile settles MPAA copyright case, agrees to $80 million in damages**
>   The MPAA represents America's major movie studios, which sued Hotfile over copyright violations in 2011. The case was finally teed up for a trial that [*was to begin*](https://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2013/12/hotfile-settles-copyright-case-will-accept-80-million-judgment/) next Monday, December 9 . — Ars Technica website, 3 Dec. 2013.
>
> At the governor's request, a health care union has postponed a strike that [*was to begin*](http://www.courant.com/business/hc-1199-withdraws-strike-notice-20150414-story.html) next week at 27 Connecticut nursing homes. *Hartford Courant* online, 14 April 2015.

An event — a civil trial or a strike called by a labor union — is either cancelled or postponed. It *was to take place* on a given date but no longer is.

Your example sentence would be both clearer and more idiomatic were it rendered:

> According to our original plan, the conference *was to begin* next Monday, but now it *is to begin/begins/will begin* tomorrow.

Comment: I agree 'was to begin' sounds better than 'began'. But I'm not asking for a rewrite, but whether the sentence on the paper is well-formed, natural English. In that paper, there's no mention of the sentence being reported speech.

Comment: Reported speech is the only way I could see that sentence being idiomatic English, thus I mentioned _was to begin_, which is idiomatic. Otherwise, it makes as much sense as _He went to Italy next week_.

Comment: I think this answer would be better if it just came out and said "nope" and used the rest of this as support for that.

Comment: @TheNate: except for the professor's note. "No" would not be a correct answer.

Comment: You could make your professor example even more parallel: *according to the syllabus, the paper was due tomorrow, but now it's due next Monday.* That sounds pretty natural to me, but somehow the Dudman quote still doesn't.

Comment: I agree that the best way to understand the past tense here is as a kind of backshift typical in reported speech.

Comment: "According to x" is a reported speech marker here.  Presumably, the beginning of the conference was given as: next Monday or a date in lieu of next Monday. How can that not be reported speech?? On the page discussing that, the author says: She returned the tickets tomorrow. And says: we say that. Well, I don't. Unless something is implied: She returned the tickets tomorrow. [according to x].

Comment: It's not clear to me where you got this idea: "Even so, if one is personally involved, i. e., you have to complete the assignment yourself rather than, say, you’re just checking for a friend, the tendency in reported speech is to use the present tense. "  Dudman's paper is talking about "our original plan", and to use a reporting verb such as 'to say', you should use a past reporting verb 'said' rather than a present reporting verb 'says': _Our original plan **said** the conference began next Monday, but now it begins tomorrow._

Comment: If I am merely attending the conference and the earlier start is no inconvenience to me, then I would backshift. If I am presenting at the conference and have to stay up all night finishing a lecture, then I'd probably couch the whole sentence in the present tense and optionally the second verb in the future because the reported speech has immediate personal effect. I found it curious how strongly Dudman disparages the _is/was to_ construction but then produces an example sentence like this one, which, though "legal," seems highly unidiomatic.

Comment: I'm not asking for your 'probably' feel. Whatever you might feel like saying in a given circumstance, once it's become a reality that "our original plan" has changed, I think it's unnatural to use the present tense "Our original plan **says**...". It's only natural to use the past tense in that case: "Our original plan **said**..."

Comment: In actual usage there are several exceptions to the backshifting rule, mostly dealing with the content/implications of the reported speech: recency, validity for the present or immediate future, urgency. See some examples here https://www.thoughtco.com/backshift-sequence-of-tense-rule-in-grammar-1689017 I'm not pulling this out of thin air.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is natural and well-formed.

Let's look at another example. Consider two friends, Fred and Joe, talking about the arrival of their friend, Mary, who lives in another town. It is Friday evening. Fred has just gotten off the phone with Mary.

> Fred: Joe, that was Mary. She got into town a couple hours ago and says she'll see you in the morning.
>
> Joe: What? I thought Mary arrived Sunday. I'm going hiking all day tomorrow.
>
> Fred: According to her original plans, yes. But her plans changed. According to her original plans, Mary arrived Sunday and left Wednesday. But she told me she  changed her plans because she got a better deal on tickets. Don't worry; she likes to hike.

Joe's use of *Mary arrived Sunday* and Fred's use of *Mary arrived Sunday and left Wednesday* are both valid syntax used when talking about the dates on/of a pre-arranged plan. Only in this kind of context do these sentences make sense and are grammatical. Joe and Fred are not talking about Mary's actual, real arrival date (she has arrived, not according to plan, on Friday evening) but the pre-arranged date of her arrival, her arrival according to the original plan, which was Sunday. In Fred's case, he even mentions Mary's pre-arranged departure date/day (Wednesday; and he can use the past tense, because he is not talking about Mary's actual departure date but the pre-arranged departure date. So, when talking about the pre-arranged plan, it doesn't matter if the actual event has happened (Mary's arrival) or not (her departure). All that matters is to be talking about the pre-arranged plan.

So, again, yes; the sentence you ask about is well-formed and natural.

One resource that discusses this use of the past-tense form is found in Palmer, *[The English Verb](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3452534-the-english-verb)*, which is cited as a reference in the paper by Dudman that you cite. And Dudman cites almost another two dozen resources, in general.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. Although people have downvoted your answer, no one has taken the time to point out what exactly it is that they don't agree with in your answer, nor has anyone been able to point out how Dudman's paper is wrong about describing the sentence as possible English.

Comment: @JK2 I'm glad you found the answer helpful. As for votes, there is so much politics behind the scenes that informs how people vote it really is ridiculous. A better site would not allow anonymous voting; that is one of the banes of this site. *Anyone*, whether a linguist or a person who barely knows English, can vote on any answer. So, the best answers don't always rise to the top, as the site info page says.

Answer (score 0):

Sentence 1: "According to our reporter from the future, the moon exploded on July 10, 3019."

Sentence 2: "According to our reporter from the future, the moon exploded next Friday."

From the reporter’s perspective the event is in the past, so the use of the past tense in both sentences seems appropriate. Sentence #1 seems grammatically conventional.  But in #1, the timeframe of the sentence originator isn't clear: is she living before or after the explosion (if before, "explodes" would be available)? But in #2 the “next Friday” is logically from the perspective of someone living before the event. There is a clash of timeframes/perspectives, but that doesn't make it ungrammatical or illogical.

I think your sentence parallels #2. The sentence originator is projecting "the plan" into the future.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is well-formed but it might not be common.

“Began” in “the conference began next Monday” conveys the fact that it was a planned event. It is not an objective fact but a wish or hypothetical. That is the purview of [English subjunctive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive). Other languages (e.g. Spanish) have special inflections for the subjunctive mood. In English, one has to manage with constructions. As explained in the linked Wikipedia page, “the name past subjunctive refers to the form of the verb rather than its meaning”. In the sentence

> According to our original plan, the conference began next Monday, but now it begins tomorrow.

everything is in the present. If one wants to stress the meanings, one can use the more common form:

> According to our original plan, the conference was to begin next Monday, but now it will begin tomorrow.

---

**UPDATE**

This update is to ask clarification from a comment by @Knotell. Please, help me by identifying which of the following statements you deem incorrect. You only need to post a number.

¶1: The verb 'to begin' has the following inflections:

- present, all persons but 3rd: begin
- present, 3rd person: begins
- past, all persons: began
- participle (past particle): begun
- gerund (present participle): beginning

¶2: Quote from Wikipedia (brackets are mine replacing 'form' with 'inflection'):

> As with the present subjunctive, the name past subjunctive refers to the [inflection] of the verb rather than its meaning; it need not (and in fact usually does not) refer to past time.

¶3: Since 'began' is the inflection of 'to begin' corresponding to the past, it can be used in the [indicative mood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Realis_mood) for the past tense or in the [subjective mood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive) in either present or past tense.

¶4: Since the tense of the verb in 'the conference began next Monday' does not coincide with the tense of the clause 'next Monday', 'began' was not used in the indicative mode.

Comment: Or, "According to our original plan, the conference would have begun next Monday, but now it will begin tomorrow."

Comment: Has nothing to do with the subjunctive.

Comment: @Knotell Please elaborate.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus I might be mistaken, but I thought that 'would have begun' is to be used in counterfactual clauses like 'If I were your wife, I would put poison in your coffee.' Maybe you could argue that the original sentence has the meaning 'If plans didn't change, the meeting would have begun …'

Comment: @Hector, I think this is a counterfactual. The plans changed. Your construction is fine, though.